# Javascript Regex

Tags: javascript

the following Regex matches to

geburtstag.d->zusatz but it should match to 
geburtstag.(*d).zusatz as well. Whats wrong?

```
new RegExp("^(geburtstag[.]\(\\*d\)[.]zusatz|geburtstag[.]d->zusatz)");
```

Comment: You need to give us examples of texts that should be matched and texts that should not be matched.

Comment: You debug your regex here. I made an example: http://regexr.com/3b1n0

Answer (score 1):

```
new RegExp("^(geburtstag[.]\(\\*d\)[.]zusatz|geburtstag[.]d->zusatz)");
// You have a duplicate \ here^
new RegExp("^(geburtstag[.]\(\*d\)[.]zusatz|geburtstag[.]d->zusatz)");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `\` in your pattern.  You weren't escaping the `*` but the `\` before it.

```
^(geburtstag[.]\(\*d\)[.]zusatz|geburtstag[.]d->zusatz)
```

Answer (score -1):

The `|` means 'OR'.  Your string matches everything after the `|`.